# Improve performance of Mongodb Collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a Collection named Time_Cube.
The given below is schema of my document. 
I want to improve performance time for all queries fetched from this collection.
I am new to Mongodb.
Can you please help me with ways to change schema or restructure queries?There are more than 3 Million records in this collection.

**P.S:** This is my first question on Stackoverflow
A sample document from the collection:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "course" : "DPP006",
        "date" : 1506384000000,
        "course_type" : "Library",
        "browser" : "Chrome",
        "device" : "desktop",
        "os" : "Windows",
        "country" : "IN",
        "language" : "enIE",
        "site" : "ea92d3b3aeb265d60ff9a91d7ab2c041",
        "cid" : "48035"
    },
    "usersData" : [
        {
            "user" : "5c5947cc03927f7eee66339b17977153",
            "cid" : "48035"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change json structure for your documents, you could use native _id, something like:

```
{
    "_id" : ...,
    "course" : "DPP006",
    "date" : 1506384000000,
    "course_type" : "Library",
    "browser" : "Chrome",
    "device" : "desktop",
    "os" : "Windows",
    "country" : "IN",
    "language" : "enIE",
    "site" : "ea92d3b3aeb265d60ff9a91d7ab2c041",
    "cid" : "48035" ,
    "usersData" : [
        {
            "user" : "5c5947cc03927f7eee66339b17977153",
            "cid" : "48035"
        }
    ]
}
```

When mongodb will insert this kind of documents, a new unique _id is created.
Starting from this, ask yourself: which kind of queries are you doing ? Where your search spend 80% of time ?
If for example your queries are all about "device", add an index on it:

db.getCollection("Time_Cube").createIndex({ "device": 1 })

For more info on how to optimize queries: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/analyze-query-plan/